# Rebuilding Fusion Drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, ssd, fusion-drive

I have a Fusion Drive (10.9.1) with a 256GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. The 1TB HDD has started making noises and has reported SMART errors. It is apparent that it will fail any day. I have Time Machine Backups, and have also purchased a new 1 TB HDD.

My question is what is the best way to restore the drive? I know I need to swap the new HDD into the array, but if I clone the old drive onto the new drive, will Fusion continue working, or will I have to restore from Time Machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to clone the drive, but had an error part of the way through that I did not notice. My solution has now been to reinstall OSX onto a new Fusion drive then restore from Time Machine. The clone method should work as far as I can tell though!